# Backbone | Script for document ready

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

There is a script(js) which I wish to run on like $(document).ready(). There is a way to write the script in template(e.g. home_tpl.html) file. But I am sure this is not a good way.

I am loading the html from a backbone view. I am not using any other wrapper like marionate. Here I wish to run some script when a template is loaded(DOM is loaded). In which way can I write the script?

Here is the rendering of view

```
 reset: function(key, email){
     require(['js/views/reset_password', 'js/models/forgot_password'], function(ResetView, ResetModel){
        var resetModel = new ResetModel();
        resetModel.set('key', key);
        resetModel.set('email', email);
        $('body').html(new ResetView({model: resetModel}).render().el);
     });
    },
```

Here is the view code

```
define(['text!tpl/reset_passwordtpl.html'],function(Template){

return Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(Template),  
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click #btn_reset_password": "reset"
    },
    reset: function(){
        if($('#reset_password').val() != $('#confirm_reset_password').val()){
            $('#error_message').text('Passwords mismatched').show();
        }   

        else{
            $.ajax({
                url: server_url + 'reset',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                data: {'id': this.model.get('email'), 'key': this.model.get('key'), 'new_password': $('#reset_password').val()},
                success:function (data) {
                    if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages
                        $('.alert-error').text(data.error.text).show();
                    }
                    else { // If not, send them back to the home page
                        $("#content").html("<h6>Your password is reset. Click <a href='#login'>here</a> to login.</h6>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```

thanks

Comment: If your code is loading the template, you know when the "DOM" is loaded, don't you (it's after you've added the content to the page). The view should contain the script, not the template.

Comment: I am rendering a view and view is loading the template. I think it loads it internally and I am not able to find a point when the template has been loaded.

Comment: How are you rendering the view? It's not automatic in Backbone. You need to call render, and in `render`, you might for example, use underscore's template compiler to create HTML, which is then inserted into the DOM. Please edit your question to include the details about where you're confused.

Comment: I had edited the question

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere you should have a main view. Where you also include stylesheets etc. At the bottom of the page just before the body closing tag. Within some script tags just do the document.ready thing.  Unless that is also in a template in which case I would consider using a different structure when it comes to views.

If you just want to do this when one template is ready loading I would use succes with a anonymous function.